# Returns text instead of image

Tags: http, url, wget

I am trying to download following comics:
`http://comicsbook.ru/upload/Комикс-Amazing-Super-Powers-Минутка-наркомании-81619.jpg`
Sorry for url, but it is just image. You can easily look it in browser, even download via browser, but if I `wget` this url, I get html page, not image. What do I do wrong? I also tried perl download module. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the referer is not set in the request, the server is redirecting(301) to a web page
I was able to get the jpg image by referer in header to: http://comicsbook.ru/funny/81619?minutka-narkomanii

```
wget --referer="http://comicsbook.ru/funny/81619?minutka-narkomanii" http://comicsbook.ru/upload/Комикс-Amazing-Super-Powers-Минутка-наркомании-81619.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

It means the default content-type is **text/html.** 
You have to set the content type you want through the **setContentType()** method of your corresponding library. Here is an example in java

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
request.addHeader("accept", "image/jpeg");
```